# AutoDisovery is selecting the wrong network interface

Tags: network-programming, realbasic

I wrote a simple application using REALBasic

The issue is that AutoDiscovery is binding to the wrong interface. The machine has 1 physical and two virtual NIC cards.

The virtual ones are there because of VMWare

How can I bind to the physical card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking at the available interfaces using NetworkInterface?  You should be able to list and select the available interfaces.

You should then be able to set the Socket.NetworkInterface property since the AutoDiscovery class is a sub of the SocketCore class.

Comment: Would you setup the Interface in App.Open ?